# PayUbiz Magento 2.3 returning 301

Tags: magento2.3

I am using this module https://github.com/payu-india/PayUbiz_Magento/tree/ver2.x It's working fine in Magento 2.2 but not working in Magento 2.3 the response URL getting 301 redirections instead of success Url

Comment: You can this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287695/getting-invalid-form-key-issue-even-if-form-key-is-valid-in-magento-2-payment-re

Comment: @PritamInfo24 Great man, Going to use this and let you know, I am sure it will resolve the issue.